# multipart/form-data using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i have the following form,

```
<form action="localhost/xyz.aspx" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="text" name="name">
     <input type="text" name="age">
     <input type="text" name="submit">
</form>
```

My requirement is to complete the action using `AJAX & jQuery` and without a form tag explicitly added in html.

TIA

## update1

i have tried

```
function onButtonClicked()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "xyz.aspx",
        data : {"name" : "john", "age" : "22"},
        crossDomain : true,
        beforeSend: function (x) {
            if (x && x.overrideMimeType) {
                x.overrideMimeType("multipart/form-data");
            }
        },
        success: function(data){
            alert("Success");
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert("on start process error");
        }
    });
}
    
    sample.html
   <html>
       <body>
            <input type="button" onclick = "onButtonClicked()">
       </body>
   </html>
```

It returns Unsupported Media Type 415.

I want send form data using ajax

Comment: @MarkLinus i ll update it

Comment: what you wont exactly, can you provide your more  code for understanding

Comment: Why does the server demand multipart/form-data when there are no files being uploaded?

Comment: @siva — What do you mean by "it is so"? Do you mean that files *are* being uploaded (and this is a cut down example that is missing a very important piece)?

Comment: @Quentin i'm using this for jBPM client. In order to access create a task i need a form with such attributes, based on my usage i cannot create a new form(UI) so providing it via AJAX call. Hope it is clear

Comment: onclick = "onButtonClicked()" so ugly ! ->      $("#formid").on("submit",function(){})

Comment: @mikakun - I suspect the OP simply created an example of what was done for the sake of showing it on here. Whilst it may be ugly, it is still valid...

Comment: so he did it in a nice way in his project but he has decided it was more appropriate to put it in an ugly way for us !?

Comment: @mikakun we can better work on the functionality. There is nothing to do with empty chats.Being beautiful and ugly is not my requirement, provide feedbacks rather than remarks. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the individual inputs and use them in an array to post. This way doesn't need a  wrapper:

```
// Click button with ID #submit
$("button#submit").click(function () {
    // Send to submit.php
    $.post("submit.php", {
        // Send these values via POST
        val1: $("#val1").val(), // Get value from input #val1
        val2: $("#val2").val()  // Get value from input #val2
    }, function(result){
        // Output result to #output element
        $('#output').html(result);
    });
});
```